# unable to iterate through list - JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

servlet code :

```
     List<Uscensuspopulationdata> ls = query.list();

      request.getSession().setAttribute("out", ls);
      response.sendRedirect("fulldata.jsp");
```

JSP code: 
           //out has represents the entire list. so out[0].name works. 
           //but i dont know how to iterate to display all the records

```
       ${out[0].name}
```

I want to display something like this:
           ${out[i].name} inside a loop so that i can get all the names from the list

Comment: Put your mouse on the `[jstl]` tag below the question until a black box pops up. Click therein the *info* link. Take your time to read it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `forEach`:

```
<c:forEach items="${out}" var="theItem">
  <c:out value="${theItem.name}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: i tried this.. but it does not work :(. nothing is being printed in jsp. if i use   ${out[0].name} i am getting it.

Comment: Did you declare the `c` taglib in your page? If you view the source of the produced HTML and you still see `<c:forEach`, you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've posted it on the session, try explicitly declaring the list in the session scope via *${sessionScope*...

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.ls}" var="e">      
    ${e.name} <br> 
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to add declaration `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>`